# CCLayer keeps shifting position

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d and have the following code which moves my layer based on the player touching the screen.  For some reason, each time the code is called the position of the layer shifts by 32 in one direction or the other.  I cant fathom why its happening.  There is no other code anywhere in the program that manipulates the position of these CCNodes (or any other Node).

```
-(void) animateStructure:(int)index And:(CCSprite*)aSprite At:(CGPoint)aPoint {
    CGPoint point1 = self.position;
    CGPoint point2 = playerSprite.position;

    id move = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(32*tempx,32*tempy)];
    [self runAction:move];    
    id move2 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.1 position:ccp(-32*tempx,-32*tempy)];
    [playerSprite runAction:move2];

    self.position = point1;
    playerSprite.position = point2;
}
```

Comment: tempx and tempy are +1 or -1 depending on which area of the screen is clicked therefore shifting the layer 32 pixels along one or two axes.  However, after each touch, they are reset to 0.  I've even put that code in this particular method to test that out, just in case.

Comment: ok. not certain how the move actions will play-out if you set the position while the action is in progress, as is the case here.

Comment: Ok. So I guess I will try a callback and set the positions after the move is done.

Comment: Ahh! That did the trick. I also set istouchenabled to false until the callback to prevent too rapid tapping from messing things up.  Thank you.  I certainly conceptually understand whats going on much better now.

Comment: yes, good idea about the touch, although .1 sec is very short, you never know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not certain how the move actions will play-out if you set the position while the action is in progress, as is the case here.